# How to select random 2 percent rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get a random 2% sample from a table in MySQL?

I tried the following queries

```
SELECT orderID
    FROM orders
    ORDER BY rand() 
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT convert(0.02 * count(*), unsigned) FROM orders)
;

SELECT orderID
    FROM orders
    ORDER BY rand() 
    LIMIT (SELECT convert(0.02 * count(*), unsigned) FROM orders)
;
```

Both of them give errors. Could someone explain error and alternate methods.

Database: Northwind

MySQL version: 8.0

Comment: LIMIT clause allows to specify returned rows amount and starting offset only. If you need 2% of rows then you must calculate total rows anount, 2% of this amount, then return rows within this row numbers range. But there is a problem - LIMIT's parameters are literals and cannot be substituted by the value calculated externally (except prepared statement). On the version 8.0 you may apply ROW_NUMBER() function in CTE and then select needed rows amount by this calculated numbers.

Comment: If table `orders` contains, hypothetically, 100 rows, then you want to retrieve two random rows from that table. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) rn, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    FROM orders
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 0.02 * cnt;  -- select first 2% of a random sample
```

Comment: Good one Tim!, Its nice that the users version is 8.0 which supports analytical functions.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Even if an earlier version, at some point only MySQL 8+ will be supported, so it would still be worth giving this answer IMHO.

Comment: I'd recommend to consider the situations when 1) `0.02 * cnt` is integer (one row will be lost, may be fixed by using soft comparing operator `<=`); 2) `0.02 * cnt` is less than 1 (the query will return nothing in this case) - may be fixed by `GREATEST(0.02 * cnt, 1)`.

Comment: @Akina Good to note that, and I also am aware of this, but keep in mind that if the OP just wants a smaller sample to do some data mining with it, plus/minus one row probably won't matter `:-)`

Comment: If I have a million rows, is using `WHERE rn < 0.02 * (SELECT count(*) FROM orders)` better than using `rn < 0.02 * cnt;` ?

Comment: @Vinay Actually no, my version is better because it saves the need to scan the entire table again when doing `SELECT COUNT(*)`.  My answer computes the total count in the same pass as the row number.

Answer (score 1):

If *approximately* 2% is sufficient, then you can just use:

```
SELECT orderID
FROM orders
WHERE rand() <= 0.02;
```

Because no sorting is required, this is probably the fastest method.

Do note that the result is not *exactly* 2% but on a large table it will be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Stored Procedure to create a function inside our MySQL.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx/

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRand2PercentSample()
BEGIN
    DECLARE nLimit INT DEFAULT 0;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) * 0.2
    INTO nLimit
    FROM orders;
    
    SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT nLimit;
END

// to call the function
call GetRand2PercentSample()
```